# How to query all ExtJS components which have some config option set

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I've specified `showCondition` custom property for some items inside view config. How can I query all such components?

I've tried [Ext.ComponentQuery.query()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery-method-query). The problem is, that `query()` returns to me correct number of elements, but there are not 'real' components, that is, when I try to do elements[0].hide(), is makes no effect.

I noticed, that when I get the same element using `ref` in controller class, `hide()` works perfectly.

After that I've `console.log`-ed results of both ways of getting the element and noticed strange things. First, returned element have different html `id` attributes (`textfield-1115` and `textfield-1089`). Second, the element which is returned by `query()` method already has hidden=true property (that's why hide() has no effect). Both elements are `textfield` components.

Below are related code parts. The important is in `onAfterRenderForm()`.

In view:

```js
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Test', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    alias: 'widget.test',

    layout: 'fit',

    initComponent: function() {
        Ext.apply(this, {
            items: [
                {
                    title: 'form',
                    itemId: 'myForm',
                    xtype: 'form',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            fieldLabel: 'code',
                            showCondition: 'is-root',
                            allowBlank: false,
                            vtype: 'alphanum'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

In controller:

```js
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Test', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.view.Test'
    ],

    refs: [
        {
            ref: 'codeField', selector: '[showCondition]'
        }
    ],

    init: function() {
        this.control(
            {
                '#myForm': {
                    afterrender: this.onAfterRenderForm
                }
        );
    },

    onAfterRenderForm: function(oForm) {
        var elements = oForm.query('[showCondition]');
        console.log(elements[0]);
        console.log(this.getCodeField());
        if(elements[0].id == this.getCodeField().id)
            alert('Elements are not the same!!!');
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that you might want to be using `[?showCondition]` if the attribute wont be inherited, but may be _falsey_, as the `?` uses hasOwnProperty as opposed to casting to bool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
refs: [{
    ref: 'codeField', selector: '[showCondition']
}]
```

is subtly different from `oForm.query('[showCondition]')[0]`.

For the `ref` you a grabbing the first component found with a defined showCondition value. In `oForm.query`, you are grabbing the first component found *that is a child of oForm* which has a defined showCondition value.

That means that if you have other fields in any view within your app that have showCondition defined on them, the call to the generated getter for the ref could return any one of those fields. It depends on what order Ext decides to put them in.

It sounds to me like a couple things are happening

1. You have other fields in your app that have showCondition defined but are not on the form your controller is looking at.
2. Your view is being rendered in the hidden state. Is is being added as an item in a card layout or something like that?

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have only one element which has `showCondition` defined and it is the element inside oForm. My view is appended to some other view as tabpanel, does that make any effect?

Comment: I've got more info :) When I use `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[showCondition]')` instead of `oForm.query('[showCondition]')` I am getting the same results and `hide()` works perfectly. I think `oForm.query` uses `Ext.dom.AbstractElement.query()` which queries HTML DOM instead of ExtJS components.

Comment: You're right, my view is being rendered in the hidden state. The problem is that my actual code is too big to post it here, so I've posted the part of it, thinking I've omitted unrelated parts of code. But in my real code I was creating a view instance and passing it to some function which was hiding elements. So, I had 2 views, one is my main view (as in posted code) and the another, which I created by mistake. And `oForm.query` worked in second view. Since second view is only in memory, I noticed no changes after calling `hide()`. I've fixed that mistake, so I have one view and all is ok now